# How to make Compose work in GTK and Qt apps?

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, gtk, qt, compose-key

I used Gnome for a long time, but preferred vanilla X input method (`xim`) over the default GTK behaviour. I just set `GTK_IM_MODULE` and `QT_IM_MODULE` environment variables to `xim`, and didn't have any problem with multiple-layout config, <kbd>Compose</kbd> key, custom `~/.XCompose` and `misc:typo` typography extensions.

Recent Gnome 3.6 completely screwed keyboard input by shipping a half-baked and buggy `ibus` [and forcing it upon the users](http://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2012/09/21/input-sources-in-gnome/). I just couldn't get the keyboard working as well as before (even with `ibus` disabled), and had to abandon Gnome completely.

Now I use a simple window manager, and configure my keyboard with `setxkbmap`. While the keyboard works well again, I couldn't get the Compose key working everywhere. Compose works in plain X11 apps (`xterm`), but it doesn't work in neither GTK2, nor GTK3, nor Qt apps.

I use current Archlinux versions:

```
xorg-xinput 1.6.0
xorg-server 1.13.1
xf86-input-keyboard 1.6.2
gtk2 2.24.14
gtk3 3.6.4
qt 4.8.4
```

and enable <kbd>Compose</kbd> key like this:

```
setxkbmap ... -option 'compose:menu'
```

and export `GTK_IM_MODULE`, `QT_IM_MODULE` variables:

```
$ echo $GTK_IM_MODULE $QT_IM_MODULE 
xim xim
```

<kbd>Compose</kbd> key is properly recognized by X11:

```
$ xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'
135 Multi_key
```

It works properly in `xterm`, sequences from my `~/.XCompose` included. It doesn't work in either GTK or Qt apps. Let say, if I enter <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd>, then apps echo `'` immediately, without waiting for the third key in the sequence.

Now I suppose something has changed in either Xorg (because <kbd>Compose</kbd> doesn't work in Qt apps either), or in GTK *and* Qt. `*_IM_MODULE` variables are not enough now. What else is required to make modern GTK and Qt recognise `xim` and its Compose sequences?

P.S. There is a similar (and unanswered) question about [Compose key not working in GTK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39547/dead-compose-keys-not-working-in-gtk-apps-since-upgrade). Unlike the asker, I don't have `ibus` installed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a solution which works for GTK apps (but not Qt). One needs to set

```
XMODIFIERS="@im=none"
```

to let X11 handle dead keys. Thanks to @PabloSaratxaga for [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65755/1662).

Comment: A solution which makes it work for QT apps, for when it works in GTK apps, is given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/595349/133286).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem in openSUSE. `~/.XCompose` would be ignored by GTK+ applications, so my own Compose sequences did not work in Firefox, Gimp, and others.

I found out that `gtk-query-immodules-2.0` listed a few input methods, but not `xim`; so, irrespective of the `GTK_IM_MODULE` variable, `xim` was unavailable. Installing the packages `gtk2-immodule-xim` (and friends) solved the problem.

Maybe this remark proves useful for people suffering from the same curse.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way of persistent configuration. It is described for example here https://wiki.edubuntu.org/ComposeKey#line-66 . I configured compose keys with ~/.XCompose this way. I have checked this both on ubuntu and debian systems.

Comment: The problem is that even the one-off method has stopped working. Instructions for persistent change are Debian/Ubuntu specific.

Answer (score 1):

For when it worked in GTK programmes, but not QT programmes, which is what I had, I found the solution [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1492313.html):

> GTK+ apps use their own copy of the Compose file from Xorg. The vast majority of compose sequences should continue to work, with a few legacy exceptions. xterm and QT apps use the XOrg compose sequences which is the `en_US.UTF-8` file in `/usr/share/X11/locate` and the `~/.XCompose` file if it exists.

Which meant for me:

```
ln -s /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose ~/.XCompose
```

and then it worked in QT programmes, too.