# Why does the system compose sequences take priority over my .XCompose file in Qt apps?

Tags: qt, compose-key

My usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose

```
<Multi_key> <minus> <greater> : "→" #Rightwards arrow
```

My .XCompose file has a similar rule with a space at the end

```
<Multi_key> <minus> <greater> <space> : "→" #Rightwards arrow
```

In xterm, the rule in my .XCOmpose file takes priority (need to type a space to input the right arrow) but in kwrite, the rule from the system compose file takes priority. Other rules in my .XCompose file that don't conflict with the system file work just fine.

**Is there a way to get the QT apps to prioritize the rules in my .XCompose?** So far the only way I can get qt to respect my rules is to not use the systme compose rules at all (by not putting an `include %L` line in my .XCompose). But this means I miss on all the useful rules in the system compose file... I guess I could copy-paste the ones I want back into my .XCompose but that would be rather annoying since there would be hundreds of rules to copy.

Comment: At a guess, they're using a different input method. Dig into KDE/Qt settings to see if there's something about input methods. See what `…_IM_MODULE` variables you have in your environment. See also [How to make Compose work in GTK and Qt apps?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60884/how-to-make-compose-work-in-gtk-and-qt-apps) and [How do I get ~/.XCompose to work on QT applications while using Ibus?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61018/how-do-i-get-xcompose-to-work-on-qt-applications-while-using-ibus)

Comment: `QT_IM_MODULE` is set to `xim`. I couldn't find anything anything related to input methods when I searched the settings. Btw, my xcompose file is not being ignored, it just has less priority if one of its rules overlaps with a system rule.